# Replacing a substring in href-attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some "a" tags in div. I have to change part of the href. For example: http://jsfiddle.net/A6z88/, I have to change only 'foo' in the href with 'asd'. Thanks a lot and sorry for my english :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('div a').each(function(){
   $(this).attr('href', $(this).attr('href').replace('foo', 'asd'));
});
```

Comment: This is not efficient, you make a lot of unnecessary call

Answer (score 2):

I'd do

```
$('#links a').each(function(){
   this.href = this.href.replace('/foo/', '/asd/'); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

See: http://jsfiddle.net/A6z88/3/

Answer (score 0):

The most elegant way with the fewest function calls is:

```
$('a').attr('href', function(i, val){
  return val.replace('foo', 'asd');
});
```

Comment: Yes this is probably the most elegant way, but i think it's not the easyest to read. It's just a personal taste, of course.